# How to install plugin to eclipse from repository

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, repository, squash

I want to install plugin to eclipse from this repository:

```
http://repo.squashtest.org/maven2/releases/org/squashtest/ta/squash-ta-maven-plugin/
```

But I have no idea how to do this. When I click on help->install new software and add this url I don't get a plugin from this site.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The url is pointing to a maven plugin of Squash.

For eclipse you have to find eclipse plugin of Squash.

Comment: Yes, but in eclipse I got an error: [ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'org.squashtest.ta:squash-ta-maven-plugin' from the repositories [local (C:\Users\...\Downloads\Squash-TA_server\repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository

Comment: that is what as eclipse installer expects eclipse plugin there but it does not find. Do you know if Squash provides any eclipse plugin at all? If yes then look for that.